# Hosting CakePHP website with SQLite DB in OPENSHIFT

Tags: php, database, sqlite, openshift, cakephp-2.3

How to configure connection setting for sqlite database in Openshift?

Below code is my connection setup in database.php:

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Sqlite',
        'persistent' => false,
        'database' => get_env('OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR').'/database.sqlite', 
        'prefix' => ''
);

}
```

I have placed my sqlite db in path: "/var/lib/openshift/~/app-root/data"

When i access the website i receive the following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')' in /var/lib/openshift/~/app-root/runtime/repo/app/Config/database.php on line 65

line 65: 'database' => get_env('OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR').'/database.sqlite',

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP you can not use a function when declaring a class property.

If you must use that function you can write:

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {
    public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Sqlite',
        'persistent' => false,
        'prefix' => ''
    );

    function __construct() {
        $this->default['database'] = get_env('OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR').'/database.sqlite';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! Will try it and let you know.

Comment: Thanks @savedario !!! it worked !!

**correct code:**
`function __construct() {
      $this->default['database'] = getenv('OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR').'/database.sqlite';
    }`